# Cpp: Do I always need to call the delete operator

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor

I have noticed something very weird yesterday.

After trying to locate where my program was crashing from, I discovered it was happening from my Error class. that was humouros. I was returning my error info as a const reference which I thought would bind.

Now, realizing the temporary wouldnt bind, I decided to return my error info as manual dynamic memory; using a ctor and dtor to "delete" the memory.

Thd WEIRD part is that I still got crash and the reason was; my destructor was getting called INDEFINITELY;

```
 // error.h
 struct ErrorInfo {};

 template <class T>
 const ErrorInfo& error(const T&);

 // Found.h
 struct Found
 {
  const char *begin, *end;
 };

 Found find(const char*,const char*);

 struct Found_ErrorInfo : ErrorInfo
 {
  const char *type;
  char fault[3];
  unsigned index;

  Found_ErrorInfo()
   : type("Not found"), fault{'\e','w',0}, index(0) {};

  ~Found_ErrorInfo() { delete this; }
 };

 template <>
 const ErrorInfo& error<Found>(const Found &f)
 {
  return *new Found_ErrorInfo();
 }

 // main.cpp
 int main()
 {
  Found f = find("dada", "I love my mama");

  if(f.begin != nullptr) std::cout << f.begin;
  else const ErrorInfo &info = error(f);
 }
```

As you can see from the sample, I return a dynamically allocated error info from the error function specialized for struct found. I then have a destructor of type Found_ErrorInfo to delete this dynamic memory/ delete itself. What happens nexg is the delete operator calls the same destructor, which again calls the delete operator and the cycle continues.

My question is, What is ths purpose of the delete operator? Is it to inform the OS that we no longer need the memory? Or just to call the destructor and then the destructor informs the OS to take back the memory.

Comment: I heard that most bugs in real code occur in error-handling code that wasn't covered by test cases

Comment: `~Found_ErrorInfo { delete this; }` is a syntax error. Please post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @M.M it's criminal, but it's not a syntax error AFAICT.

Comment: With modern C++, it's almost *always* better to use smart pointers.

Comment: *What is ths purpose of the delete operator?* The `delete` operator 1. calls the destructor to perform any clean-up, such as putting away any resources the object holds, and then 2. it returns the memory used by the object. Knowing that `delete` will call the destructor, think on what will happen if you `delete this;` inside the destructor.

Comment: Thank you user4581301. Now I know that the delete operator is neccessary to return back the memory. Now I need a hack. If I use a smart pointer it gets destroyed when error() returns. I guess I will have to find a way to return an object instead.

Comment: @M.M turns out I have built-in autocorrect in the eyes, especially at 2 AM. 

Comment: *If I use a smart pointer it gets destroyed when error() returns.* Return the smart pointer so that ownership is passed to the calling function. The smart pointer not only manages the memory for you, it also gives readers of your code a clear indication of the owner of the memory.